# Programmatically destroy a component from other component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

In my vue app some particular components in`router-view` are cached by using `<keep-alive></keep-alive>` that vue provides.

When a user logs in the **posts.vue** component is cached as I said above

Everything works fine.

Now I want to **destroy**  this **posts.vue** component when the user logs out.So that `posts.vue`  component re-renders when the user logs in again

The log out button is present in completely other component `menu.vue` and the on click logic for log out is present in this `nenu.vue` component

So how could I implement this using `vm.$destroy()` method from `menu.vue`  component on `posts.vue` component

**so my main problem is how to control lifecycle of one component from the other**

the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-destroy) warn using this as follows :,

**In normal use cases you shouldn’t have to call this method yourself.**

**Prefer controlling the lifecycle of child components in a data-driven fashion using `v-if` and `v-for`.**

**but in my case I cant use `v-if` or `v-show`**

*or is there any better way i could use*

Comment: What is happening right now when the user logs in again and tries to access posts.vue?

Comment: @Deepak the previously cached posts are also being displayed.... so i want this component forcefully re-render when the user logis in again

Comment: If you can post the done inside the posts.vue might be helpful. The functions that gets the data should be called inside the created hook. And that should take care of it.

Comment: @Deepak could not understand it... could you please elaborate a bit more... thanks

Comment: You would have written a function which is getting the posts from some api. So where are you calling this function?

Comment: @Deepak the api fetch, updatimg, is being done via vuex

Comment: Please provide some fiddle, or the code inside the posts.vue.

Comment: @Deepak yup i will ...

Comment: @Deepak https://jsfiddle.net/77uovfe7/   heres the link

Comment: Try https://jsfiddle.net/deepaksingh/77uovfe7/1/

Answer (score 1):

When you log in or log out from child component, emit 'login' or 'logout' event respectively.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view name='login' @login="login=true"></router-view>
    <router-view name='header' @logout="login=false"></router-view>
    <keep-alive v-if="login">
      <router-view name='write'></router-view>
    </keep-alive>
    <router-view name='management'></router-view>
    <router-view name='account'></router-view>
    <router-view name='statistics'></router-view>
    <router-view name='view'></router-view>
    <router-view name='password'></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      login: true
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and one simple solution I found was to force reload the web application via `location.reload()`, which clears the `keep-alive`.

You might also find this discussion interesting: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6259

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty easy way to do this. Thanks to @loomchild for the link.

You can define on routes a `meta` object. Define it in such a way for routes using keep-alive that you want to invalidate.

```
    {
        path: '/invalidate_me',
        ...
        meta: {uuid: generateUUID()} // You'll need a method for this or something similar
    },
```

Check out [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript) for help with UUID if need be.

Then, in your keep alive definition:

```
      <router-view :key="$route.path + ($route.params.id ? $route.params.id : '').toString() + ($route.meta && $route.meta.uuid ? $route.meta.uuid.toString() : '')"></router-view>
```

Something like that. If you don't include ids or don't want to cache by those, fine. Those are not related to the question, but something that I am using. So you really only need the `meta` part. We're basically telling Vue to consider a component to be defined by the combination of the id on the route (if it exists) and the uuid on the route (if it exists)

Then, when you want to invalidate inside a component, change the uuid. You may need to find the route in the lists on $router, or if you're already inside the correct component, you can do:

```
this.$route.meta.uuid = generateUUID();
```

This gets a new uuid and clears the cache.

Hope this helps someone else!